# Angular app nginx config, handle aws load balancer base path

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-elb

I'm trying to get an angular container running behind an AWS load balancer.
The load balancer serves other apps based on routes eg. `elb.amazonaws.com/some-path`

I started with this nginx.conf which works when accessing the container directly, but not behind the LB due to the `/some-path` that's also passed to the app.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
    }
}
```

I tried updated `location /` to `location /some-path/`
The first request to the app returns index.html correctly, but the subsequent calls fail as the base path disappears and is hitting nothing on the LB e.g.
**RequestUrl:** elb.amazonaws.com/runtime.js instead of `elb.amazonaws.com/some-path/runtime.js`
I noted below on the request headers it has the Referer correctly
**Referer:** elb.amazonaws.com/some-path/

I've tried to add different combinations of `/some-path/` in location and try_files, and some other config in the app, but to no avail.
The only way I managed to get this working was to copy the app into a sub directory `/usr/share/nginx/html/some-path` and set that in try_files

```
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ $uri $uri/ /some-path/index.html =404;
    }
```

Then add it to index.html `<base href="/some-path/">`

Is there another way to handle this,(e.g. .net apis fix this with app.UsePathBase) without having to move the app to a subdirectory dictated by it's LB path?

Many thanks.